# Listview data to another Listview

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have two listview controls, each having the same column headers. Listview1 contains the master data table and listview2 has a much smaller set of data that I need to add to the Master in Listview1. I can add this new data to the bottom of the main data in Listview1 using the AddRange option, but I need to add it to the top of the data in Listview1 but cannot see how.

If anyone can help I would appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

Thank you for your comments, which I have taken on board.

Let me add some more detail and some code. The data in Listview2 is a monthly csv file input which I read into the Listview2. The data is a set of details with the first field being the date, the most recent date at the top of data. I package this data as an array and attempt to load in into listview1, the master file, with the exact same fields and date order. Here is the code I have used to load the csv and the code to place the packaged data into Listview1. The only problem with this is, it places the data at the end of the current file in Listview1, so it would be out of sequence, so I am trying to place it at the top of the current file in Listview1.

```
    ' load the file into listview with this quick routine.
    Dim CSVTest As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    CSVTest = File.ReadAllLines(ImportDirname).ToList
    Dim ColNames As List(Of ColumnHeader) = New List(Of ColumnHeader)
    Dim ColumnArray() As String = CSVTest(0).Split(",")
    For i = 0 To ColumnArray.Count - 1
        ColNames.Add(New ColumnHeader)
        ColNames(i).Name = ColumnArray(i)
        ColNames(i).Text = ColumnArray(i)
    Next
    ListView2.Columns.AddRange(ColNames.ToArray)
    'This adds the rest of the data from the file to the listview. 
    For I = 1 To CSVTest.Count - 1
        Dim col() As String = CSVTest(I).Split(",")
        Dim NewLVItem As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem(col(0))
        NewLVItem.Name = col(0)
        For j = 1 To col.Count - 1
            NewLVItem.SubItems.Add(col(j))
        Next
        ListView2.Items.Add(NewLVItem)
    Next (I)

    ' this adds the range to the bottom of the listview data
    ' - not what is required. I need it at the top !!!!!
    Dim Items(ListView2.Items.Count - 1) As ListViewItem
    For i As Integer = 0 To ListView2.Items.Count - 1
        Items(i) = CType(ListView2.Items(i).Clone, ListViewItem)
    Next
    ListView1.Items.AddRange(Items)
```

Again if anyone can help I would be grateful.

Comment: You need to show some effort on your own problem.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  Thank you in advance

Comment: [**`ListView.Items.Insert()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.insert(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try Something Like This

```
With lst1. Items.**Insert**(0, "Sample", 0)
.SubItems.Add(2)
.SubItems.Add(3)
.SubItems.Add(4)
.SubItems.Add(5)
.SubItems.Add(6)
.SubItems.Add(listDownload.Count - 1)
```

End With

Hope this can help you